# Array of hashmap with one hashmap

Tags: java, arrays, nullpointerexception, hashmap

Im working on a school assignment, and im supposed to make a array of hashmap like this:

```
HashMap<String, Person>[] mood = (HashMap<String, Person>[])  new HashMap<?, ?>[6];
```

im reading from a file, it goes something like this. the problem is that it gives  NullPointerException where i try to put the mood into mood[0]! cant find anything about how the hashmap-array works in my books.. :( would be happy for all help (:

```
Person p = new Person();
p.name = word[1];
p.age = word[2];
p.mood = word[3];

people.put(p.name, p);

 if (p.mood.equals("HAPPY")) {
 mood[0].put(p.mood, p); //NullPointerException 
 }
```

Comment: Hint: the first element of an array does not have an index of 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, you did initialize an array of mood, but it's initialized with `null`s. So before you can call any method on mood[0] (or at any other indices), you need to put a non-null object inside mood[0].

Comment: i didnt know about it before now, im sorry. will fix it now.  but thanks!

Answer (score 1):

When you create arrays of objects, the array elements are initially null, so before using `mood[0]`, you need to populate it with an instance of `HashMap<String, Person>`